# Perform calculation on one column based on other columns in an R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an R data frame that looks something like this:

```
Company Date         Number
ACoy    2015-08-28   1000
ACoy    2015-08-29   1300 
ACoy    2015-08-30   1500
BCoy    2015-08-30   3000
CCoy    2015-08-30   2000
CCoy    2015-08-31   3000
ACoy    2015-08-31   1500
BCoy    2015-08-31   3000
CCoy    2015-09-01   3500
CCoy    2015-09-02   1000
ACoy    2015-09-02    900
CCoy    2015-09-03   2000
BCoy    2015-08-31   3000
CCoy    2015-08-31   3000
```

How can I perform a calculation on Number based on the value of Company, but only after a specific date?

Specifically, I am trying to get `Number = Number/3` where `Company == ACoy` and `Date > 2015-08-30`

Result:

```
Company Date         Number
ACoy    2015-08-28   1000
ACoy    2015-08-29   1300 
ACoy    2015-08-30   1500
BCoy    2015-08-30   3000
CCoy    2015-08-30   2000
CCoy    2015-08-31   3000
ACoy    2015-08-31    500
BCoy    2015-08-31   3000
CCoy    2015-09-01   3500
CCoy    2015-09-02   1000
ACoy    2015-09-02    300
CCoy    2015-09-03   2000
BCoy    2015-08-31   3000
CCoy    2015-08-31   3000
```

Comment: I think it has been asked several times here, and also answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that the `Date` column is already classed as such.

```
## determine which rows match the specified condition
w <- with(df, Company == "ACoy" & Date > "2015-08-30")
## replace only those 'w' values with the specified calculation
df$Number <- replace(df$Number, w, df$Number[w] / 3)
## result
df
#    Company       Date Number
# 1     ACoy 2015-08-28   1000
# 2     ACoy 2015-08-29   1300
# 3     ACoy 2015-08-30   1500
# 4     BCoy 2015-08-30   3000
# 5     CCoy 2015-08-30   2000
# 6     CCoy 2015-08-31   3000
# 7     ACoy 2015-08-31    500
# 8     BCoy 2015-08-31   3000
# 9     CCoy 2015-09-01   3500
# 10    CCoy 2015-09-02   1000
# 11    ACoy 2015-09-02    300
# 12    CCoy 2015-09-03   2000
# 13    BCoy 2015-08-31   3000
# 14    CCoy 2015-08-31   3000
```

Comment: Thank you! note you have an extra `)` on the `df$Number...` line

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed now.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Based on the condition in the 'i' (`Company=='ACoy' & Date > '2015-08-30'`), we assign 'Number' as the `Number/3`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[Company=='ACoy' & Date > '2015-08-30', Number:= Number/3]
```

NOTE: We assume that 'Date' column is `Date` class and the 'Number' is `numeric` class.

Comment: Wow I had no idea you could write it like that.  Nice one